# HTML DOM - localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom

I was trying to make a basic sign-up/login thingy using localStorage in JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>login</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id = "userSave">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input id = "passSave">
    <button onclick = "saved()">save</button>
    <h2 id = "textSave"></h2>

    <h1>sign up</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id = "userLoad">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input id = "passLoad">
    <button onclick = "loaded()">load</button>
    <h2 id = "textLoad"></h2>

    <script>
        function saved() {
            let text = document.getElementById("textSave").innerHTML;
            let username = document.getElementById("userSave").value;
            let password = document.getElementById("passSave").value;

            localStorage.setItem(username, password);
            text = "saved";
        }

        function loaded() {
            let text = document.getElementById("textLoad").innerHTML;
            let username = document.getElementById("userLoad").value;
            let password = document.getElementById("passLoad").value;

            if (localStorage.getItem(username) == password) {
                text = "welcome";
            }
            else {
                text = "login failed";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked everything. Spelling, onclicks, function names, and most of the stuff is fine, but it won't work properly

Comment: Check the browser's console to ensure no obvious javascript errors are logging.

Comment: You are just setting a string to a variable, `text` is not connected to your element, ie setting the variable will not change the element's text

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what “doesn’t work properly” means here? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you mean with "it doesn't work", is that you don't see any DOM changes. Strings are immutable so it counts as a "pass by value".

If you want to make DOM changes, then instead set your text reference to the element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>login</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id = "userSave">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input id = "passSave">
    <button onclick = "saved()">save</button>
    <h2 id = "textSave"></h2>

    <h1>sign up</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id = "userLoad">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input id = "passLoad">
    <button onclick = "loaded()">load</button>
    <h2 id = "textLoad"></h2>

    <script>
        function saved() {
            let text = document.getElementById("textSave");
            let username = document.getElementById("userSave").value;
            let password = document.getElementById("passSave").value;

            localStorage.setItem(username, password);
            text.innerHTML = "saved";
        }

        function loaded() {
            let text = document.getElementById("textLoad");
            let username = document.getElementById("userLoad").value;
            let password = document.getElementById("passLoad").value;

            if (localStorage.getItem(username) == password) {
                text.innerHTML = "welcome";
            }
            else {
                text.innerHTML = "login failed";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Side note: I realize this is for practise, so I won't dig to deep into it - but storing passwords as plaintext, and on the client (and doing client validation for passwords) is never a good idea for any real projects

Answer (score 0):

first thing do you need is fix your logic for login and sign up flow. You can separated this with 2 different page. usually, we can login if we have an account (Username or Password) and sign up if we haven't username and password.

You can see bellow logic for login like

```js
var usernameKey = "admin"
var passKey = "admin"
function saved(){
        let username = document.getElementById("userSave").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("passSave").value;
    if((username == usernameKey) && (password == passKey)){
         console.log("condition when Username & Password True")
    }else{
             console.log("Username Or Password False")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="signIn">
    <h1>login</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id="userSave">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input id="passSave" type="password">
    <button onclick="saved()">save</button>
    <h2 id="textSave"></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And A Sign Up Like:

```js
function loaded(){
        let username = document.getElementById("userLoad").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("passLoad").value;
    
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    localStorage.setItem("password", password);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="signUp">
    <h1>sign up</h1>
    <h2>username</h2>
    <input id="userLoad">
    <h2>password</h2>
    <input  id="passLoad">
    <button onclick="loaded()">load</button>
    <h2 id="textLoad"></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this help you to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be coming from your saved function, you are trying to set the text variable to "saved", but you're not updating the HTML element with this value. You should use document.getElementById("textSave").innerHTML = "saved"; to update the text:

```
<script>
function saved() {
    let text = document.getElementById("textSave");
    let username = document.getElementById("userSave").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("passSave").value;

    localStorage.setItem(username, password);
    text.innerHTML = "saved";
}

function loaded() {
    let text = document.getElementById("textLoad");
    let username = document.getElementById("userLoad").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("passLoad").value;

    if (localStorage.getItem(username) === password) {
        text.innerHTML = "welcome";
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = "login failed";
    }
}</script>
```